# Problem with the responsive of Datatables, size of column it's to bigger to the normal

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I'm using Datatables and encoutered problem with the reponsiveness of the datatables with the size of columns.
When datatables are defined the size of column, that is bigger and the last column of the table is no displayed.
So I have tried to add a CSS class with a `max-width`, but it is not working.

HTML :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<table class = "display" id = "datatable"></table>
```

CSS :

```
.cell_table {
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

JS :

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "columnDefs" : [{
        "targets": "_all",
        "createdCell" : function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            $(td).attr('id', 'cell-' + col);
        },
    }, {
        "targets" : [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "className" : "text_center cell_table",
    }],
    "lengthMenu" : [[5, 10, 20, 30, -1], [5, 10, 20, 30, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength" : -1,
    data : data_use,
    columns : column_name,
    dom : 'lfrtip',
    responsive : true,
    destroy : true,
    searching: true,
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/98twhpyo/8/) you can find the code on JSfiddle.

Comment: Try to recreate the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/onLuw2pa/).

Comment: @wazz The problem is only on Safari and Mozilla Firfox (sorry iI forgot to mention it) , [here](https://jsfiddle.net/98twhpyo/8/) you can find the code on JSfiddle.

Comment: I have also seen this issue on Firefox -- the Javascript for the datatables doesn't always correctly set the column sizes. Setting the CSS is worthless because it will always be overwritten by the Javascript set "Style" values.

Comment: I dont see class names assigned to cells! and is not working on chrome either

Comment: I think this is a bug with Datatables and should be taken up with them.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong, setting className twice which apparently not correct.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ef8rtL9c/)**

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
            "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
            "columnDefs" : [{
                "targets": "_all",
                "createdCell" : function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    $(td).attr('id', 'cell-' + col);
                },
            }, {
                "targets" : [0, 1, 2, 3],
                "className" : "text_center cell_table",
            }],
            "lengthMenu" : [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength" : 25,
            data : data_use,
            columns : column_name,
            dom : 'lfrtip',
            responsive : true,
            destroy : true,
            searching: true,
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.text_center{ 
    text-align : center;
}

.cell_table {
    max-width : 250px;
}

.dataTable{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. The Datatable still sets `style="width: 1044px;"` for the `<table>` element in a window that is far smaller.

Comment: @Martin we are talking about single cell here, not the entire table.

Comment: @SebCollard I see the case Martin mentioned now, but FYI happens on chrome as well, so let me check.

Comment: Here: https://ibb.co/kxXGBDw and https://ibb.co/TmMBPxv (before and after). Note the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: @Martin How did you get the scroll bar ?

Comment: @SebCollard by resizing the window after page load. See the *before* and *after* `;-)`

Comment: ok the main issue is that parent table width changes from inside JS library, and it has a priority over cell max width, as temporary solution if you can keep the table width static it will allow max cell width to be applied, as a test I set width to 100% and it works. give it a try.

Comment: Sorry,  Prolly, this **does work**, but when *expanding* the window the datatable stays at the original size.

Comment: @Martin I did not quite understand this, would you clarify pelase?

Comment: @ProllyGeek . 1) Load the fiddle. 2) resize the output to be larger than the original. The table does not expand with the window expansion. 3) Shrnik the window to smaller than the original size and the table scales correctly. `:-)`

Comment: @Martin Yes, but this issue exists from fiddle not from my changes, you can obviously see it in old fiddle. Try this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/qzkg763t/3/